# ProtectedData Security- Accessing Encrypted Data on a Different Machine

Tags: c#, .net, dpapi

I'm using the Local Machine Scope to protect software specific data.

```
ProtectData.Protect(Byte[], Byte[], DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine)
```

If someone copies the ProtectedData to another system it wont work right?
Is it because of the password is different? What exactly is the thing that prevents access of encrypted data on a different machine.

- I understand parts of user password is used to create a Masterkey

-This master key changes when the user changes his password automatically ie: the thing simply works.But it also says that if an Admin Resets the password the Data will no longer be accessible.What is that scenario?

-In the LocalMachine mode how is the MasterKey generated.Its not the password alone right? Since its applicable to all the users on the system.

Basically im looking to replace hardware id with this.

What im trying to achieve is the same functionality of what a hardware based encryption.Is that possible using ProtectData? Simply i dont want the secret to be accessed on a different system

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx

Comment: @SLaks Thanks.I have gone through that already.What im trying to achieve is the same functionality of what a hardware based encryption.Is that possible using ProtectData? Simply i dont want the secret to be accessed on a different system.

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypt with machine scope, anyone who can read local disk can decrypt.
No passwords are involved.

Comment: What you mean by read local disk? Like read the files from ubuntu? Please be clear.Then what are the parameters used for encryption in this mode

Comment: @techno: Yes.  I don't know the algorithms involved, but all of the key material is on disk.

Comment: I know the keys are stored on disk.Where is this key material stored? How is decryption possible? Steps to support your argument . Im looking for a detailed answer on this.

Comment: hmm.... But im not looking for a bulletproof method to secure data.This thing requires medium technical knowledge i presume.Just a way to prevent casual piracy.Like you know copying stuff from one person's computer to another.

Comment: If you copy this protected data to another computer, then on that computer it will be secure, because the key data is not present. Edit: The articles posted spell that out clearly.